# Not subsequently used dataflow task warning

Tags: ssis

"The output column "A" (67) on output "Output0" (5) and component "Data Flow Task" (1) is not subsequently used in the Data Flow task. Removing this unused output column can increase Data Flow task performance."

Please resolve my problem

Comment: Please explain your problem...

Comment: want to remove warnings like to improve performance

Answer (score 8):

These warnings indicate that you have columns in your data flow that are not used. A Data Flow works by allocating "buckets" of fixed size memory, filling it with data from the source and allowing the downstream components to directly access the memory address to perform synchronous transformations.

Memory is a finite resource. If SSIS detects is has 1 GB to work with and one row of data will cost 4096 MB, then you could have at most 256 rows of data in the pipeline before running out of memory space. Those 256 rows would get split into N buckets of rows because as much as you can, you want to perform set based operations when working with databases.

Why does all this matter? SSIS detects whether you've used everything you've brought into the pipeline. If it's never used, then you're wasting memory. Instead of a single row costing 4096, by excluding unused columns, you reduce the amount of memory required for each row down to 1024 MB and now you can have 1024 rows in the pipeline just by only taking what you needed.

How do you get there? In your data source, write a query instead of selecting a table. Don't use `SELECT * FROM myTable` instead, explicitly enumerate all of the columns you need and nothing more. Same goes for Flat File Sources---uncheck the columns that are never used. You'll still pay a disk penalty for having to read the whole row in but they don't have to hit your DF and consume that memory. Same story for any Lookups - only query the data you need.

[Asynchronous components](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jorg_klein/archive/2008/02/12/ssis-lookup-transformation-is-case-sensitive.aspx) are the last thing to be aware of as this has turned into a diatribe on performance. The above calculations are much like freshman calculus classes: assume a cow is a sphere to make the math easier. Asynchronous components result in your memory being split before and after the component. They radically change the shape of the rows going through a component such that downstream components can't reuse the address space above it. This results in a physical memory copy which is a slow operation.

My final comment though is if your package is performing adequately, finishing in an acceptable time frame, unless you have nothing else to do, leave it be and go on to your next task. These are just warnings and should not "grow up" to full blown errors.

Comment: +1 for the educational answer;  but wouldn't 4096 KB be a more typical example row size than 4096 MB?

Comment: @criticalfix True and originally I had used KBs but then decided I didn't want to do the extra conversion math ;)